# Are there any packages offering search tools for dictionaries, lists etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

For example, a function that when provided a dictionary and a value, would return the key that first contained said value. Or maybe a function that could return all keys containing a certain value, etc. Is there a dedicated package for things like this?

Comment: I don't think you need a package/library just for this. I mean, it's hardly a few lines of code to implement what you're asking.

Comment: They were just examples, though, I was just wondering if there was a package that included a wide variety of tools for the purposes of indexing, organizing, structuring dictionaries, and possibly other data structures. If there was, then it would mean that it is professionally written and optimized and could be used with ease for whoever needed it, without needing to create what would likely be a less clean version for themselves.

Comment: Python's native modules _already_ has a wide variety of tools for the purposes of indexing, organizing, and structuring dictionaries and other data structures. Just because it's a 3rd party library does not mean it's professionally written, and just because it's a built-in/native library does not mean it's not yet optimized and/or not easy to use. You'll have to be more specific in what kind of data structure and operations do you need.

Answer (score 1):

The two things you want to do can be realized by using list comprehension. But in a dictionary, there is no order. So you cannot just get the first element.

```py
d = {"One": 1, "Two": 2, "Three": 3, "Four": 3}
ks = [v for k, v in d.items() if v > 1]
```

I think many [built-in types, such as int, str, list, set, dict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html) have many methods that are very convenient but one may not know about. So I first recommend you to read them thoroughly.

Also, in my experience, there are two modules [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools) and [collections](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#module-collections) that are worthy to learn and use. Here are the information from the docs.

[itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools):

> This module implements a number of iterator building blocks inspired
>   by constructs from APL, Haskell, and SML. Each has been recast in a
>   form suitable for Python.
>
> The module standardizes a core set of fast, memory efficient tools
>   that are useful by themselves or in combination. Together, they form
>   an “iterator algebra” making it possible to construct specialized
>   tools succinctly and efficiently in pure Python.

Here is a screenshot from the docs showing a little part of it.
[image]
[image]

[collections](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#module-collections):

> This module implements specialized container datatypes providing
>   alternatives to Python’s general purpose built-in containers, dict,
>   list, set, and tuple.

[image]

Comment: The two modules that you mentioned look really interested, I'll be sure to give them a thorough read very soon! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't need any external package to get the keys, Use the below definition to get all the keys for given value

```
def getKeys(dictionary, value):
    keys = []
    for key in dictionary.keys():
        if dictionary[key] is value:
            keys.append(key)
    return keys

a = {"One": 1, "Two": 2, "Three": 3, "Four": 3}
print getKeys(a, 3)
```

(Or) simply

```
def getKeys(dictionary, value):
    return [key for key in dictionary.keys() if dictionary[key] is value]
```

This will return all the keys with same value